json_encode() output space fetching from PHP-string
<script>
  const text2 = <?php echo json_encode($kallory, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
  
  let index2 = 0;

  function type() {
    document.getElementById('typewriter').innerText += text2[index2];
    index2++;
    if (index2 < text2.length) {
      setTimeout(type, 30);
    }
  }

  type();
</script>

And my $kallory-string from PHP
$kallory = 'Word1\xa0Word2\xa0Word3\xa0Word4';

And the output:
Word1\xa0Word2\xa0Word3\xa0Word4
I have tried with \xa0,   and also just 'Word1 Word2 Word3'.

What is your question exactly?

It looks like you're asking why the whitespace characters are missing from the output. It happens, because innerText strips the leading/trailing whitespace when the content is viewed on the page. Use regular spaces instead of \xa0s in PHP, and textContent instead of innerText in JS.

Alternative solution: build the output in a variable and use ....innerText = textOutput instead of +=

Problem solved:
Use regular spaces instead of \xa0s in PHP, and textContent instead of innerText in JS.
Before:
document.getElementById('typewriter').innerText += text2[index2];

After:
document.getElementById('typewriter').textContent += text2[index2];

